# How to represent sections in math notation? E.g. (_ + 3)

Tags: notation, partial-functions

Functional programming languages have the concept of sections where they can partially apply a function that is represented by an operator.
For instance, one can define a function that always adds three to its argument $f(x) =x+3$ and use it $f(2)$, or avoid having to define the function/argument just by using sections : $(\_ + 3)$. Some contrived use would be $(\_ + 3)(2)$.
Is this _ notation currently known in academic math texts?

Comment: It is usual to define a function using $\cdot$. For example, the function that assigns $\langle x,y\rangle$ to $x$ can be denoted as $\langle\cdot,y\rangle$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Lambda calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus). For your example we could write the function application as
$$(x\mapsto x+3)(2)=2+3=5$$